# What else does the < operator do in python?

Tags: python

Besides being a less than operator, it seems to be doing something else here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage import filters

camera = io.imread("img.png", True)
val = filters.threshold_otsu(camera)


newImg = camera < val ######?

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(newImg, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But I'm not sure what is going on, and the result is not a boolean. There doesn't seem to be anything online either.

Where can I read more about what this operator is doing?

Comment: I’m guessing it’s an array of `<` performed on each corresponding element of the arrays?

Comment: Why do you think the result is not a boolean array?

Comment: `camera` is a Numpy array that represents the image data; the `<` operator is being broadcast across that, as explained in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, `<` is acting as an [array comparison](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less.html).  Here you are comparing an array representing the image, with a value representing a threshold.

The result will be an array of booleans, representing those values that are less than the threshold.

For example:

```
>>> numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) < 3
array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot

Answer (score 3):

Any object can overload comparison operators by [defining the right methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> ```
> object.__lt__(self, other)
> object.__le__(self, other)
> object.__eq__(self, other)
> object.__ne__(self, other)
> object.__gt__(self, other)
> object.__ge__(self, other)
> ```
>
> By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful
>   comparison. However, these methods can return any value […]

So, it's up to the object what exactly a `<` operation yields.